# SQL Server 2008 R2 connection string error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-r2, connection-string

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 running but when I try to connect to the server via my C# connection string I receive an error. I have no clue of what the problem is!

Here is my connection string:

```
_msConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=ServerIpAdress;Database=DataBaseName;User Id=NetworkName\\UserName;Password=PW;");
```

I hope some of you guys can help me?

Have a great day you all!

Comment: Is that the ACTUAL connection string you're using?

Comment: try with `Id=UserName` only instead of `Id=NetworkName\\UserName`

Comment: Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and attepmt to continue. If you click Quit, the application will close immediately. ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed

Comment: I have tried it with Id=username but I get the same error

Comment: you have actually forgot to open the connection, the problem is not with the connection string..!! after creating a connection you should open the connection created.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9707060/3030434 refer the answer here..!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/839031/3030434

Comment: "Unhandled exception has occurred in your application" - mybe learn some basic debugging and showing the real exception text? I mean, come on, people learn that part in week 1.

Comment: Solved it. Problem was windows authentication! Now i used own authentication:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Id=NetworkName\\UserName
```

sounds a bit strange, try

```
Id=username
```

Also if you can connect to the DB using MS VS, MS SMS or any other likely tools your app can connect passin exactly same paramenters.

Other things to check: Actual user running the app (IIS_USR maybe)
In your SMS or VS you can get the actual connection string being used and just copy past it.